# CUrL PHP 7 : installed but not detected or loading

Tags: php, linux, curl, detection

I work on a Debian Linux 8 PHP 5 / PHP 7 / PHP 7.1
I installed CUrL extension but it's not detected.

> curl --version
>   curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
>   Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

Do you know from where could come the issue?
Many thanks

Comment: In the terminal, if you send a "php -m", curl appears on the list? If appears, what the code used to call curl

Comment: You need to the php bindings for curl. debian or ubuntu has package php-curl. $ apt-get install php-curl